# Node / Express Can't set headers after they are sent when adding <% include %>

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a can't set headers after they are sent error only after adding a <% include partials/file %>.

Route:

```
router.get('/blog', function(req, res) {
  shopify.article.list(86289414)
    .then(function (response) {
      response.reverse();

      response = response.map(function(element) {
        return {
          author: element.author,
          blog_id: element.blog_id,
          body_html: element.body_html,
          created_at: element.created_at,
          handle: element.handle,
          id: element.id,
          image: element.image,
          published_at: element.published_at,
          summary_html: element.summary_html,
          tags: element.tags.toString().toLowerCase(),
          template_suffix: element.template_suffix,
          title: element.title,
          updated_at: element.updated_at,
          user_id: element.user_id
        }
    })

    var data = {
      articles: response.map(function (article) {
        return {
          author: article.author,
          id: article.id,
          html: article.body_html,
          tags: article.tags.split(","),
          date: moment(article.published_at).format("Do MMM YYYY"),
          slug: article.handle,
          title: article.title,
        } // return
      }) // map
    } // data


    shopify.article.tags(86289414)
      .then(function (response) {

        var sorted = [];  // Lowercase becauwse /search is case sensitive (indexOf)
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { // Lowercase becauwse /search is case sensitive (indexOf)
          sorted.push(response[i].toLowerCase());  // Lowercase becauwse /search is case sensitive (indexOf)
        }  // Lowercase becauwse /search is case sensitive (indexOf)
        sorted.sort();  // Lowercase becauwse /search is case sensitive (indexOf)

        var dataTwo = {
          data: data,
          tags: sorted,
        }

        res.render('blog' , dataTwo)


      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err) );
      //res.render('blog', data);

  }) // then
    .catch(err => console.log(err) )
});
```

If I remove the partial hamburger it works fine. All of the other partials are uneffected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" / />
    <meta name="author" content="SemiColonWeb" />

    <!-- Stylesheets
    ============================================= -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icons.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blog.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Document Title
    ============================================= -->
    <title>Blog</title>

</head>

<body class="stretched">

    <!-- Document Wrapper
    ============================================= -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix" >

        <!-- Header
        ============================================= -->
                    <% include snippets/header %>

                            <!-- Page Title
        ``============================================= -->
        <section id="" style="background-color:#72109e;height:300px;color:#fff;">

            <div class="container clearfix center blog-header">
                <h1 style="padding-top:70px;font-style:sans-serif;font-size:5rem"><span style="color:#fff;">Welcome to Dome's Z-Wave Blog</span></h1>
                <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight: lighter;margin-top:-30px;">Browse more than 100 interesting articles, how-to's and industry news about Z-Wave.</p>

            </div>

        </section><!-- #page-title end -->

        <!-- Content
        ============================================= -->
        <section class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div style="margin: 50px 0 0 0; padding: 3rem 3rem 3rem 3rem; border: solid #d3d3d3 1px; ">
                        <h4>Tags:</h4>

                    <% tags.forEach(function(tag) { %>
                        <a href="/search/<%-tag %>"><%- tag %>,</a>
                    <% }) %>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-10">

                    <!-- Posts
                    ============================================= -->
                    <div id="posts">


                        <% data.articles.forEach(function(article) { %>
                        <%- include('snippets/blog-post', {article: article}) %>
                        <% }); %>


                    </div><!-- #posts end -->


                </div>

            </div>

        </section><!-- #content end -->

        <!-- Footer
        ============================================= -->
        <% include snippets/footer %>

    </div><!-- #wrapper end -->

    <!-- Go To Top
    ============================================= -->
    <div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>
    <% include snippets/hamburger %>



    <!-- External JavaScripts
    ============================================= -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

    <!-- Footer Scripts
    ============================================= -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hamburger:

```
<div id="side-panel-trigger" class="side-panel-trigger product-page" style="position: absolute; left: 2rem; top: -1rem; z-index: 200 !important;">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="icon-reorder" style="color: white; font-size:2rem;"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Error middlewhere

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  //err.status = 404;
  res.redirect('/404');
  next(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call both `res.redirect()` and `next(err)`.  Also, if you're hitting that middleware it's probably because the include is giving you some other error that causes you to catch it there.